# How to say "I think studying English is easier for Brazilians than for Japanese"

Tags: grammar, translation, comparative-constructions

I wanna say "I think that for Brazilians, studying English is easier than it is for Japanese"

I know how to make simple comparisons like

> お寿司の価格の方がラーメンより高い

but I am having trouble coming up with that sentence, specifically because the only place I can check if it is right is Google translator, but I know it is not reliable... my attempt is:

> ブラジル人にとって英語を勉強する方が日本人にとってより簡単だと思うよ

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually mean "the act of studying" the languages, or do you actually mean "learning" the languages?

Comment: @istrasci learning!

Comment: Also, AFAIK, 方 is written in hiragana when used in comparisons.

Comment: @istrasci oh I didn't know that, even so Yuuichi Sam seems to have used the kanji as well

Comment: @istrasci I think it's often written in hiragana, but writing it in kanji is not uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your attempt is a literal translation. I translate it as ブラジル人が英語を習得する(覚える)方が日本人より簡単だと思うよ.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's funny how your answer fits my idea of parsing in comparisons but the other one it's kinda different, both right I guess。本当にわかりやすい

Answer (score 2):

how about something like

> ブラジル人の方は日本人より英語をならうのが簡単です。

Comment: cool, so I need  to let the "complex" part at the end? the whole "learning" thing. And the comparison is just "to brazlians is easier than to japanese"?

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna say "I think that for brazilians, studying english is easier
>   than it is for japanese"
>
> > ブラジル人にとって英語を勉強する方が日本人にとってより簡単だと思うよ

I think it's a good try, but a little confusing.
It's easier to understand if it's like this:

> **1** 英語の勉強**は**ブラジル人にとって**の方が**日本人にとってより簡単だと思うよ。

See it's more similar to you sample sentence:

> （ふつう**は**）お寿司の価格**の方が**ラーメンより高い

This can be also like this:

> **2** ブラジル人**が**英語の勉強を**する**の**は**日本人が英語の勉強をするより簡単だと思うよ。
>   or
>   **3** ブラジル人**が**英語を勉強**する方が**日本人が英語を勉強するより簡単だと思うよ。

I find when I see the sentence starts with ブラジル人**にとって**, I expect it to be followed by **～は**. In other words, I seem to expect **～にとって** to be a *modifier to the theme* of the sentence.

> ブラジル人**にとって**英語を勉強すること**は**、日本語を勉強するより簡単だと思うよ。
>    [Comparing studying English and studying Japanese, both for Brazilians]

Comment: I understand the Idea, I like the fact how it can be worded in so many different ways, just one question is "にとって" natural in this case? it feels like it was one of the things that made Yuuichi Tam think that my sentence was too "literal"

Comment: When you pick the #1 from my examples, you can omit にとって, but I don't say it doesn't go well in your case. The にとって just makes the expression more accurate.

Comment: are にとってのほう and/or にとってより grammatical?  they sound a bit strange to me.

Comment: For most of the occasions they are fine. We use の to make anything in front of it into a noun. OK. I show you in the order from logically loose to strict here:  英語の勉強はブラジル人の方が日本人より簡単だと思うよ＜英語の勉強はブラジル人にとっての方が日本人にとってより簡単だと思うよ＜ブラジル人にとって英語を勉強することは、日本語を勉強するより簡単だと思うよ。How's that? :)